# UIDate Picker SET Difference Time from Curret Time To Double

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, uidatepicker

i have ***UIDatepicker*** that set to  time mode.
i want to ask the user to set the time that he began some action, and i want to get the Difference from the Current time To Double.
please guys if someone knows please help me out :-)

tnx!

Comment: Can you explain your question little bit?

Answer (score 0):

`UIDatePicker` gives you a `(NSDate *)date`, which can be used to compute a time difference with `[date timeIntervalSinceNow]`, which returns a `NSTimeInterval` which is actually a float in seconds.